# Why child div is shifted some pixels down and some pixels left from the parent div?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Child div is shifted some pixels down and some pixels left from the parent. I am concerned about the class "yellow" that is child of class "red". Here is my code:

```css
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:solid 2px;
}

.red{
    background-color:red;

}
.yellow{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">red
  <div class="yellow">yellow</div>
</div>
<div class="green">green</div>
```

Comment: I see the problem on zoom (125% and some higher zoom).

Comment: Do you need yellow inside red div?

Comment: @Cédric I understand that the child div yellow sits on top of parent div red . But why the child does not completely overlap the parent? and if there is some auto margin to child div yellow i am not able to see while inspecting and checking the css box model.

Comment: @yousoumar I am not able to understand why yellow is not completely overlapping the red and why some amount of margin or padding is getting added to the child and relative to what is the child getting the spacing?

Comment: In the removed screen provided, we could see some red space between red and yellow div borders, explaining my first comment that I see that red space on zoom. I'm wondering where it comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

border:solid 2px; is the reason, here child div border width 2px is occupying space.

Replace border with an outline like below

```css
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    outline:solid 2px;
}

.red{
    background-color:red;

}
.yellow{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">red
  <div class="yellow">yellow</div>
</div>
<div class="green">green</div>
```

Comment: But why there is some space above yellow div?

Comment: You added the text "red" in the red div, it occupies some space, right?

Comment: Oh !! right got it ..silly me